# Can someone explain me meaning of ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Could you pl explain me what is the meaning of **ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING** in Oracle analytical function.

The full calculation is as below.

```
SUM(WIN_30_DUR) OVER(PARTITION BY AGENT_MASTER_ID ORDER BY ROW_DT ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
```

Thanks

Comment: The windowing clause for analytic functions is [explained in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#i97640).

Comment: You have enough explanation in your previous post.